# Assigning Freemarker variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, freemarker

I want to assign a value inside javascript value

```
function abc(){
var b = document.getElementById("tc").value;
if(b=="true"){
<#assign x=true>
}
else{
<#assign x=false>
}
}
```

however I am not able to get value of x. Can someone please let me know how to assign freemarker variable inside javascript.

Comment: Please format your code... You may be able to assign the value of `x` to a JS variable (like `var jsX = ${x};` and then `alert( jsX );` - I am not sure about the freemarker syntax but it may be close to get you going

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done. Javascript is evaluated in the browser and FreeMerker is evaluated on the server before it gets to the browser. If you are generating the JS through FM such as in a  script block of a html file then what the browser will see is

```
function abc(){
    var b = document.getElementById("tc").value;
    if(b=="true"){

    }
    else{

    }
}
```

You can verify this by looking at the source in the browser (for FireFox right click and select View Page Source).